# How can I change logging level across all endpoints using Spring Cloud Bus?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator

I have two Spring Boot instances and when I change the logging level of one I want it to automatically propagate to the other.  I've snooped around and I get the impression that this can be done using Spring Cloud Bus with RabbitMq and actuator, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.  The dependencies I've cobbled together in an attempt to accomplish this are...

- spring-boot-starter-actuator v1.5.2
- spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp v1.3.1

My RabbitMq instance is on another server.  When I spin up the instances I see both making a connection to Rabbit and they both create a spring_cloud_bus.anonymous queue.  I change the logging level on instance 1 via actuator like this...

`curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v1+json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{"configuredLevel": "DEBUG"}' 'http://{instance 1}/management/loggers/{some component}'`

When I query instance 1 I see the logging level did indeed change, but no change to instance 2.  What else do I need to do to make this work or am I completely barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: What versions are you using?

Comment: /management/loggers isn't a bus endpoint. /bus/env is. You post to it the same value you would put in application.properties

Comment: @spencergibb Thanks! I have edited the question with versions.

Comment: @spencergibb I just tried it and it works.  Thanks a ton!